# Компиляция DLL и LIB

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019

Есть чужой код C++ в котором есть код:

```
// FlySofa.h
#ifdef FLYSOFA_EXPORTS
#define FLYSOFA_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FLYSOFA_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <FlySofaSource\Sofa.h>
```

В чужом коде *FLYSOFA_EXPORTS* создается автоматически и позволяет использовать один и тот же заголовочный файл как для компиляции LIB/DLL так и для подключения к ним. Когда я пересоздаю проект самостоятельно это волшебное определение пропадает.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.

"Скрытые/неявные" определения *#define* можно указать в *свойствах* проекта в разделе *препроцессор*

Внесение *FLYSOFA_EXPORTS* в определения *препроцессора* дало требуемый результат.